# How to concatenate two DB fields in a Spinner (Android)

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I have a database table with first_name and last_name in two separate columns.  I want to display them as "Smith, John" on a Spinner.  I can show one of the names with no problem using a SimpleCursorAdapter.  I thought in order to show both columns, I would have to extend CursorAdapter.  I have this working ok, but I am not sure if I need to make a custom layout for the spinner?  Every CustomAdapter example that I can find is using a list view, not a spinner.  Here is what I have in my bindView method of the CustomAdapater:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    String first = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Hunter.FIRST_NAME));
    String last = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Hunter.LAST_NAME));
    nameTextView.setText(last + ", " + first);
}
```

Obviously, this does not work because the view passed in does not contain android.R.layout.simpler_spinner_dropdown_item, so nameTextView is null.  How do I get at the text field on a spinner?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you can't.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639306/populating-an-android-spinner-from-an-sqlite-but-with-two-fields

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to inflate your layout in newView method. try this

```
View view = View.inflate(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
return view;
```

and then in bindView

```
TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
//the rest
```