# Populating an Android Spinner from an SQLite but with two fields?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

I've finally managed to populate a spinner from an sqlite db after much messing about with this code however it's only using one field and I want First and Last names on the same spinner item?

The code is as follows:

```
    private void fillSpinner() {
    Cursor c = myDbHelper.FetchDrivers();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
    String[] from = new String[]{"FirstName"};
    // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    // create simple cursor adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    // get reference to our spinner
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spr_Driver1);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now it displays the FirstName and I've tried added "FirstName", "LastName" but it doesn't do anything different, I ideally want it to display the name in full on each spinner item. Is this even possible?

Any help would be great!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to change the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`, as these layout items are able to display only one item in the dropdown list and on the spinner.
For your purpose, the best way is to create your own layout that has two items.
[Here](http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/03/using-custom-layouts-for-spinner-or-listview-entries-in-android/) is a link about how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, Just what I wanted and it looks like it might also solve something else for me as well!